# Stream to LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to save .csv to LinkedHashSet with natural order, so the first line of the .csv should be a first element of the LinkedHashSet.

the file look like this:

```
java  
c  
c++  
assembly language  
swift
```

and my code like this:

```
public class test {   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {         
         final Charset ENCODING = Charset.forName("Cp1250");
         Path fileToLoad = Paths.get("src/main/resources/test.csv");
         Set<String> x = Files.lines(fileToLoad, ENCODING)
                 .map(Function.identity())
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());

         Iterator<String> it = x.iterator();
         while(it.hasNext()) {
             System.out.println(it.next());
         }
    }
}
```

but it returns incorrect order:

```
assembly language
c++
java
c
swift
```

I think that stream just save it as HashSet.

Is it possible to save it as LinkedHashSet with stream?

Comment: That's because `Collectors.toSet()` won't use a `LinkedHashSet` but just a `HashSet`. Try `Collectors.toCollection( LinkedHashSet::new )` instead.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a `List` structure, which is ordered, rather than a `Set` which isn't;

Comment: from the javadoc *This is an unordered Collector* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You simply don't know the specific type created by that factory method (it [guarantees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--) to return *Set*, nothing else).

The only reliable way is to actually *control* what happens, by ending the stream operation with

```
... collect( Collectors.toCollection( LinkedHashSet::new ) );
```

Comment: omg, I'm stupid. Thank you. 

Comment: @mondjunge Sure not. It seems obvious, but I do remember that I stumbled over this when I first read the question back then.

Answer (score 3):

The `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` does not create a `LinkedHashSet`, but rather a regular `HashSet`.
Rather use `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)` to ensure that a `LinkedHashSet` is being used.

Answer (score 1):

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this set. The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator()

Use `List` rather than `Set`.

Comment: Note that the OP stated he wants to use `LinkedHashSet` which would iterate over the elements in insertion order. So using set and iterator is fine here, he just needs to use the correct implementation.

Comment: @Thomas youre right, this solves the problem a different way than the OP asked

Answer (score 0):

A set is typically unordered but there is a ordered set which is not as efficient in the storage process but retains order and unique elements only

Check if you can use this: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Collection/0110__Java_Sorted_Set.htm